# Edit simultaneously many buffers and save all of them after edit

Tags: buffers, text-editing

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

I open 3 different files:
[image]

I need:

1. Edit simultaneously all buffers. Add text "`customer/`" to the node `"bodyFileName"`in all buffers.
2. After edit save all buffers,

Here result:
[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: I like using the `grep-mode` and then `wgrep` to edit multiple buffers and save, and I also use `multiple-cursors` when in `wgrep` mode.  There are undoubtedly other methods ...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to to use **multi-occur-in-this-mode**. To do that process as follows:

1. open all the files you want to process (`C-x f` then *.json)
2. `M-x multi-occur-in-this-mode` then enter your search string ("bodyFileName" for instance)
3. then in the occur buffer, enter edit mode by typing `e`
4. here you can do your search and replace as usual `C-x %` for instance. For each json buffer where a match occurs you will be prompted for modification.
5. once that you have modified all you want you can leave occur edit mode by `C-c C-c`
6. to close occur buffer type `q`
7. save all modified buffers: `C-x s`

---

**Update** Omar is right, I have `multi-occur-in-this-mode` function in my Emacs config for so long.... that I completely forgot that it is not a built-in function but a function described in [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/searching-buffers-occur-mode).

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl))

(defun get-buffers-matching-mode (mode)
  "Returns a list of buffers where their major-mode is equal to MODE"
  (let ((buffer-mode-matches '()))
   (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
     (with-current-buffer buf
       (if (eq mode major-mode)
           (add-to-list 'buffer-mode-matches buf))))
   buffer-mode-matches))

(defun multi-occur-in-this-mode ()
  "Show all lines matching REGEXP in buffers with this major mode."
  (interactive)
  (multi-occur
   (get-buffers-matching-mode major-mode)
   (car (occur-read-primary-args))))
```

Comment: I have not command "multi-occur-in-this-mode". I has only "multi-occur-in-matching-buffer".

Comment: You can also use this command: simply fill "..filenames match regexp" with "json$", then you will be asked for "lines matching regexp" -> enter "bodyFileName", then continue (continue from step 3)

Comment: It's work but after I change 3 buffers. It's ask me to save it. But I want by ONE command to save all 3 buffers.

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. To save all buffers, did you try `C-x s` ?

Comment: `C-x s` will ask you for each buffer whethere you want to save it or not, but you can also do `C-u C-x s` which saves all without prompting.

Comment: I think the mysterious `multi-occur-in-this-mode` command, might be from this [Mastering Emacs blog post](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/searching-buffers-occur-mode).

Comment: @omar thanks for the extra information. You are right.

Comment: @Omar "C-x s" also help. After it ask me to save buffer I select "!" and Emacs save ALL edited buffers.

Comment: I find more simple approach. Use package "xah-find" - https://github.com/xahlee/xah-find. It's replace text in files in folder.